# Leibnitz theorem when limits of integration is from 0 to infinity

Tags: integration

Given that
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\alpha}f(\alpha)=-\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}\sin(\alpha x)\ \mathrm dx$$
Where
$$f(\alpha)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(\alpha x)\ \mathrm dx$$
The value of $f(2)$ is

$(A)\quad\alpha e$

$(B)\quad\frac{\alpha}{e}$

$(C)\quad\alpha\sqrt{e}$

$(D)\quad\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{e}}$

How to apply Leibniz theorem for differentiation under integral sign if the limits of integration is from 0 to infinity?

And if Leibniz is not the correct way to go for this sum how to solve it otherwise?

Comment: Did you try using $\sin(x)=I(e^{ix}$

Comment: @Archis Welenkar did you solve it using the method you stated ?

Comment: Yes  but i dont know whether its right so not giving any answer

Comment: Hope some good calculus guy gives it so that also i can learn

Comment: @Archis Welenkar which option did you get correct ??

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it
$$f(\alpha)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(\alpha x)\ \mathrm dx$$
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\alpha}f(\alpha)=-\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}\sin(\alpha x)\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=-\frac{\alpha}{2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(\alpha x)\ \mathrm dx$$
First note that
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\alpha}f(\alpha)=-\frac{\alpha}{2}f(\alpha)$$
$$f(0)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\ \mathrm dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$$
So now
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\alpha}f(\alpha)=-\frac{\alpha}{2}f(\alpha)$$
$$\frac{2}{f(\alpha)}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\alpha}f(\alpha)=-\alpha$$
$$\int\frac{2}{f(\alpha)}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\alpha}f(\alpha)\ \mathrm d\alpha=-\int\alpha\ \mathrm d\alpha$$
$$2\int\frac{1}{f(\alpha)}\ \mathrm df(\alpha)=-\frac12\alpha^2+C$$
$$\ln f(\alpha)=-\frac14\alpha^2+C$$
$$f(\alpha)=Ce^{-\frac14\alpha^2}$$
And
$$f(0)=Ce^{0}$$
$$C=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$$
Therefore
$$f(\alpha)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}e^{-\frac14\alpha^2}$$
And
$$f(2)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2e}$$